# Which is quicker - on the fly html or creating elements with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
object.innerHTML = "<div class='panel'>foo |</div>"
```

or

```
panel = document.createElement ("div");
panel.setAttribute ("class", "panel");
panel.innerHTML = "foo |";
object.appendChild (panel);
```

Say I'm creating a lot of divs on the fly (around a hundred or so), each with event actions, class and id names, which would be the more efficient way? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

#### About practicality

Provided you have the correct XSS security in place, I find the ease of use of `innerHTML` far more important then the speed benefits of potentially using the DOM.  Using `innerHTML`  you can simply write HTML.

#### Actual Speed in Browsers

Depends on the browser, innerHTML is generally faster in IE.  DOM manipulation is commonly faster in chrome, but as always it depends on the use case.

The Chrome, Firefox, Safari speeds are so fast its pretty much irrelevant.
Considering IE is typically one of the slower browsers, I would advise using innerHTML to help IE along...  `innerHTML` is almost always faster in IE.

source:
http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml/10

If you are adding tons of elements, `innerHTML` is very often the way to go.